# I think this question should be either migrated or deleted, I believe my flag should not have been declined

Tags: support, declined-flags, migration

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845126/need-to-understand-the-concept-of-patterns-in-programming) for migration, it was *declined* because it was already closed.

> extremely off-topic here belongs on
>   softwareengineering.stackexchange.com if anywhere – Jarrod Roberson 23
>   hours ago   declined - The question has already been closed. I don't
>   see any point in changing the close reason from "unclear" to
>   "off-topic".

It was drawing *reopen* votes, it was at `2` now it is now at `3` is why I flagged it for migration, it is something that should be re-opened on [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

It should either be deleted or migrated but it definitely should not be allowed to be re-opened.

Answer (score 11):

You don't flag a question for migration to lock it from gathering reopen votes. That is an abuse of the migration feature.

You flag a question for migration when it is on-topic and good enough for the intended destination site.

There are no provisions to regular users for queuing a question that's neither spam, rude/abusive, or complete garbage for speedy deletion, or for preventing a closed question from gathering reopen votes.

If the question really is eligible for migration, then the *only* path to getting it migrated is to first reopen it. It *is* appropriate to flag a closed question for this reason, although be prepared to make a good case for it (for example, if the question already has answers — if it doesn't, it might be easier for the asker to cross-post it and for the closed stub to be deleted separately, and some actually do).

Migrating to a site that's not in the default set requires a mod to "close" it as off-topic->belongs on another site in the network and then enter the destination site. So technically, it needs to get re-reopened and then vote closed..

Comment: `There are no provisions to regular users for queuing a question that's neither spam, rude/abusive, or complete garbage for speedy deletion` You mean mod deletion, right?  Because...delete votes...

Comment: @Servy: Yes, because even delete votes take time to accumulate, and whether they accumulate faster than reopen votes depends on who does what first. Jarrod could cast a delete vote right now and it could take either 2 minutes or 2 days for the rest of the delete votes to follow - by which time the question may or may not have been reopened.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson: OK, I might have misunderstood your post. If the question really is eligible for migration, then the *only* path to getting it migrated when it has been closed is to first reopen it.

Comment: @BoltClock - thanks for that clarification, I thought when it got migrated it got re-opened automatically.

Comment: @Jarrod migrating to a site that's not in the default set requires a mod to "close" it as off-topic->belongs on another site in the network and then enter the destination site. So technically, it needs to get re-reopened and then vote closed... Migration isn't a separate thing from closing...

Comment: @JonClements - thanks for the information, regular uses do not know these things!

Comment: Migration is easy if there is no answer - the OP copypastas the question to a suitable site and deletes it from SO.  There - migrated!

Comment: Migration works exactly the same way for regular users, @Jarrod. It is a special case of closure, accessible via the exact same "close" pop-up dialog. The only difference here is that [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) is not one of the "unlocked" migration paths for regular users, so you need a moderator to migrate a question there. In this case, it's hard to see why the question you flagged should have been migrated elsewhere at all. Even after the edit that clarified it, it still looks to me like it would be "too broad" for Software Engineering.